# The following action types are invalid: read error with GraphAPI facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a weird problem with the facebook GraphAPI , I created a new action called "read", and then this was succesfully aproved by Facebook. Now I try to put my new action in some social widgets, but I have the error "The following action types are invalid: read" .. what is going on?

a pic with the problem:

[image: the error]

Answer (score 1):

> what is going on?

This is going on: [Platform Updates: Operation Developer Love
from May 31th, 2012 um 01:00](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/30/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)

> Additional publishing guideline
>
> For stories about watching a video or reading an article, you **must** use the *built-in* watch and read actions. We’ll no longer approve custom actions for these stories.
>
> Even if we’ve approved your custom action for reading an article or watching a video, you **must** migrate to using a built-in action, resubmit your app and get approved.